# Command to get different strings from a line in shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, substr

I have a text file. Some of the sample lines in the file are as below

```
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.ErrorNotify' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.Output' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.LogRequest' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.Router' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.RouteMessage' on jvm group 'JVM123' is stopped.`
```

I am tryng to get the output using a single shell command as

```
com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput,running
com.java.abc.ErrorNotify,running
com.java.abc.Output,running 
com.java.abc.LogRequest,running
com.java.abc.Router,running
com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen,running
com.java.abc.RouteMessage,stopped`
```

I tried using substr and awk.

I tried `cat textfile.txtt|awk '{print substr($4,2,length($4)-1)}'|sed "s/'/ /g"` and `cat textfile.txt|awk '{ print $4,$10 }'|sed "s/'/ /g"` but can't get the desired result.

Please help.

Update: If my text file is something like this

```
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:44 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/SupportToolsOutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-44-27.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 5:02 PM'
UUID: 'f9a9f0cb-3401-0000-0080-b85eb6410185'
Start mode: 'Maintained'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'BackOutThreshold' = '1'
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
  'MaxPerInterval' = '5'
  'NotificationInterval' = '300'
Keywords:

--------
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.ErrorNotify' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:45 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/ErrorNotifyDEV_2012-01-11_02-45-45.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 5:04 PM'
UUID: 'efcff1cb-3401-0000-0080-b85eb6410185'
Start mode: 'Maintained'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
  'MaxPerInterval' = '5'

Keywords:

--------
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.Output' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:46 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-46-44.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 3:30 PM'
UUID: '1fbbf2cb-3401-0000-0080-b85eb6410185'
Start mode: 'Maintained'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'BackOutThreshold' = '1'
  'BasicAuthorization' = 'YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ='
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
  'MaxPerInterval' = '5'
  'NotificationInterval' = '300'
  'ProxyAuthorization' = 'QTkwNzk2MzpnNzVuajZqcQ=='
  'isSslSecured' = 'FALSE'
Keywords:

--------
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.LogRequest' on jvm group 'JVM123' is running.

Additional thread instances: '4'
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:48 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/LogRequestDEV_2012-01-11_02-48-54.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 4:00 PM'
UUID: '60b4f4cb-3401-0000-0080-b85eb6410185'
Start mode: 'Maintained'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'EVENTTYPE' = 'Integration_RequestSent'
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
  'MaxPerInterval' = '5'
  'NotificationInterval' = '300'
  'SOARTMCompliant' = 'FALSE'
Keywords:

--------
MESS01: Java flow 'com.java.abc.Router' on jvm group 'JVM123' is stopped.

Additional thread instances: '4'
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:49 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/RouterDEV_2012-01-11_02-49-32.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 4:10 PM'
UUID: '8d46f5cb-3401-0000-0080-b85eb6410185'
Start mode: 'Maintained'
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'BackOutThreshold' = '1'
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
  'MaxPerInterval' = '5'
  'NotificationInterval' = '300'
Keywords:
--------
MESS02 : Java file 'Integration.jar' on on jvm group 'JVM123'. 
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:46 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-46-44.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/12 4:10 PM'
Keywords:

--------
MESS02 : Java file 'SAPAdapter.adapter' on on jvm group 'JVM123'. 
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:46 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2011-11-10_22-55-55.bar'
Last edited: '1/10/14 14:55 PM'
Keywords:
```

---

And i want my output as

```
JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-46-44.bar,Integration.jar
JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2011-11-10_22-55-55.bar,SAPAdapter.adapter
JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/SupportToolsOutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-44-27.bar,com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput,running
 JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/ErrorNotifyDEV_2012-01-11_02-45-45.bar,com.java.abc.ErrorNotify,running
 JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-46-44.bar,com.java.abc.Output,running 
JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/LogRequestDEV_2012-01-11_02-48-54.bar,com.java.abc.LogRequest,running
 JVM123,/www/deploy/JVM123/RouterDEV_2012-01-11_02-49-32.bar,com.java.abc.Router,stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one grabs state on seeing *MESS01* and prints on *Deployed*. It uses a simple and direct regex for field delimiter:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -F "[ ']" -v OFS=, '/^MESS01:/ { sub(/\.$/,""); o=$5; j=$11; s=$NF; } /^Deployed:/ { print j, $(NF-1), o, s }' textfile.txt
```

Tested it... and it produces what you want.  Notes:

- No **cat** was harmed in the mangling of this script. ;)
- Your log looks to be all ASCII and using LC_ALL=C will likely make the script dramatically faster.
- Using NF helps to avoid any issues with the date and is intuitive (in the answer, I am telling the reader that my intent in the code is to look at the last field in one case and next to last field in the other).
- The reason for the sub() in *MESS01* is that adding a "." in the delimiter regex would kill your object.
- In the future, you may find it better to just use space for the delimiter and filter out ^'|'$ in jvm, object and path using gsub() -- in this case you would want to pass the filtering regex as a variable  (due to quote confusion).

Here is a version using the gsub() mentioned in the last point:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v OFS=, -v r="^'|'$" '/^MESS01:/ { o=$4; j=$8; s=$NF; gsub(r,"",o); gsub(r,"",j); sub(/\.$/,"",s) } /^Deployed:/ { p=$NF; gsub(r,"",p); print j, p, o, s }' textfile.txt
```

Comment: I have some more line in the above text at the end as follows
`MESS02 : Java file 'Integration.jar' on on jvm group 'JVM123'.
Deployed: '1/11/12 2:46 AM' in Bar file '/www/deploy/JVM123/OutputDEV_2012-01-11_02-46-44.bar'`
I am using your awk command to get Mess01 part and using the same command slightly modified `awk -v OFS=, -v r="^'|'$" '/Mess02:/ { o=$3; j=$9; gsub(r,"",o); gsub(r,"",j); sub(/\.$/,"",j) } /^Deployed:/ { p=$NF; gsub(r,"",p); print j, p, o }' textfile.txt` Is there a way to do it all in a single command? Also my modified command is spitting out Mess01 parts too. Please help.

Comment: please find my updated text file and output needed in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F "[' ]+" '{print $4 "," $NF}' textfile.txtt
com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput,running.
com.java.abc.ErrorNotify,running.
com.java.abc.Output,running.
com.java.abc.LogRequest,running.
com.java.abc.Router,running.
com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen,running.
com.java.abc.RouteMessage,stopped.`
```

To remove one `DOT` from last field use:

```
awk -F "[' ]+" '{sub(/\./, "", $NF); print $4 "," $NF}' textfile.txtt
```

Answer (score 1):

yet another `awk`

```
$ awk -v q="'" '{gsub(q,""); print $4 "," $NF}' log

com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput,running.
com.java.abc.ErrorNotify,running.
com.java.abc.Output,running.
com.java.abc.LogRequest,running.
com.java.abc.Router,running.
com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen,running.
com.java.abc.RouteMessage,stopped.
```

this one to remove the last period if important

```
$ awk -v q="'" '{gsub(q,""); sub(/\.$/,""); print $4","$NF}' log

com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput,running
com.java.abc.ErrorNotify,running
com.java.abc.Output,running
com.java.abc.LogRequest,running
com.java.abc.Router,running
com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen,running
com.java.abc.RouteMessage,stopped
```

Comment: Similar, but I'd prefer `awk -v q="'" -v OFS=, '{gsub(q,"",$4); print $4,$NF}'`. Why? So that you're only modifying what you know you want to modify (what if there's a single quote embedded somewhere in the first three fields?) and you have the option of other output using the correct field separator rather than mashing strings together. (Nevertheless, this gets my vote.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
 cat test.txt|awk -F\  '{ print $4","$10 }' | sed "s/\'//g"|sed "s/\.$//"
```

gives

```
com.java.abc.SupportToolsOutput running
com.java.abc.ErrorNotify running
com.java.abc.Output running
com.java.abc.LogRequest running
com.java.abc.Router running
com.java.abc.ProcessMessageNextGen running
com.java.abc.RouteMessage stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

For perspective, here's a sed solution.

If you're just parsing text as per your example, the following might suffice:

```
sed "s/[^']*'//;s/'.* /,/" logfile
```

The two sed commands here (1) strip everything up to the first single quote, and (2) replace everything from the next single quote to the last space on the line.  Add `;s/.$//` to this to strip the trailing period.

If you're parsing the larger log that you added in your update, you'd need to adjust this a little.  The following will produce your originally requested output using the expanded log:

```
sed -n "/^MESS01:/{;s/[^']*'//;s/'.* /,/;p;}" logfile
```

This does the same as the earlier script, but only on lines that start with `MESS01:` .. and it also only prints the lines that match that pattern.

For the output you mention at the bottom of your question, I don't recommend you use sed, as you need to pull data from different fields in a log that essentially has multi-line records. It may be possible with sed, but it will be extremely complicated. Awk is much better at that.